# SFMC SMS Next keyword replies

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sms

I am looking to send an SMS and when they respond send them an answer.  I have the next keyword set up and I can customize answers based on if the reply is Yes or No.

```
%%[
var @response, @validResponse
set @response = [MSG(0).NOUNS]

if IndexOf(@response, 'no') > 0 then
]%%

Thank you for your response! Someone from our team will reach out to you to follow up.
%%[
    endif
]%%

%%[  
    if IndexOf(@response, 'yes') > 0 then
]%%

Thank you for your response!

%%[ endif ]%%
%%[ endif ]%%
%%[ else ]%%
```

But what I want to do is set a reply for 'No' and then any other reply besides no gets a different reply.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
%%[
var @response, @validResponse
set @response = [MSG(0).NOUNS]

if IndexOf(@response,'no')>0 then
  set @validResponse = true
endif

if @validResponse == true then

]%%
Thank you for your response! Someone from our team will reach out to you to follow up.
%%[ else ]%%
Thank you for your response!
%%[ endif ]%%
```